# Escape Dust.js Tag

Tags: javascript, templates, node.js, dust.js

**TLDR; skip to the bottom paragraph for the main question.**

I'll try to keep this nice and concise by leaving out *why* I want to do this, and the context surrounding it. But as a minimum, I have Node.js running on the back-end, rendering out every view using Dust.js.

Then I also have a client-side copy of Dust which dynamically renders interface elements as needed. When this goes into production, I'll pre-compile all of my client-side Dust templates, and avoid this problem completely. However, during development, testing would be much simpler if I could keep my templates inside of DOM elements. However, these "sub-templates" get mangled because the tags intended for use in client-side templates get filled with null values (because I failed to provide them to the server-side renderer).

Say I have this template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="some_template_to_be_rendered_client_side">
        <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like the {title} template tag to be filled in by the Node.js Dust when the template is rendered out, but I'm looking for a way to *escape* the {description} tag so that I can dynamically compile and render template on the client-side using the HTML within the div as the template.

Comment: Actually you answered the why in the middle paragraph. You want to have it run a certain way during test to prove how things work on the client.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are special escape tags that you can use to escape a raw `{` or `}` in dust.  They are `{~lb}` and `{~rb}`.

E.g.

```
{~lb}hello{~rb}
```

would render as

```
{hello}
```

Comment: Bingo! It's not pretty, but that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Are there other options?  Doing a global search/replace is impossible because of the braces.   What a poor choice of escape character by Dust developers!

Answer (score 0):

You can scape five special chars only [ docs: https://www.dustjs.com/docs/syntax/ ]

> {~special}
> A special is converted to a special character
>
> A special is a single opeing curly brace {, followed by a tilde ~, follwed by any of the characters in a reference, followed by a single closing curly brace }. Dust supports five “specials”:
>
> {~s} becomes a single space
> {~n} becomes a new line
> {~r} becomes a carriage return
> {~lb} becomes a left curly brace {
> {~rb} becomes a right curly brace }